# Python. Проверить, является ли число степенью тройки. Выводит None

Tags: python

```
def is_power_three(n):
    print(n)
    if n == 1:
        return 'Є степенем трійки'
    if n < 1:
        return 'Не є степенем трійки'
    is_power_three(n/3)


n = int(input('Введіть N: '))
print(is_power_three(n))
```

Обязательно использовать рекурсию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш метод в конце концов ничего не возвращает, сделайте вот так:

```
def is_power_three(n):
    print(n)
    if n == 1:
        return 'Є степенем трійки'
    if n < 1:
        return 'Не є степенем трійки'
    return is_power_three(n/3)
```